# Initialize Mobile Push SDK twice in Mobile App

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android, mobilepush-ios

I have a use case where I need to send a push notification to the same mobile app from two different business units.

For that, I created a Mobile Push app under Mobile Push administration in both Business Units.

The idea is to initialize Mobile Push SDK twice with parameters from App 1 and App 2 in order to register in both of them.

Did you already have this use case ?

I am also exploring other possibilities like custom activities but I rather stay close to standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the Android and iOS support the ability to switch between different business units, but there is no support for multiple business units to be active at one time.

Comment: Here is what I did and It worked for two applications in the same Business Unit. I initialized the SDK with parameters from App 1 and run the mobile app. the device was then registered with App 1. Then I pushed parameters from App 2 to the mobile app and relaunched it. The device was then registered with App 2 and stayed registered with App1. From Marketing Cloud I was able to send a push to the mobile app from App 1 and App 2.

Comment: As I said, it's not supported.  That might work for now, but there is no telling what will happen in the future.  Over time the registration of the first BU used will likely become incorrect since it is no longer being updated.  This could leave that device absent of any list you might create to target them.