# Mobile push using one Mobile App and Multi Org/multiple BUs

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, sfdcmobilesdk-android

We have the following structure:

1. Parent BU

1.1 Child BU A - connected to SFCRM Org 1

1.2 Child BU B - connected to SFCRM Org 2

We want to develop a Mobile App and push notifications to the relevant contact, using its respective BU's journeys and automation.

There are no duplicate contacts, each org has its own separate contacts that are synced into MC respective BU.
We know that all contacts are shared and can be accessed from all BUs, but for this use case, I wanted to clarify that there are no duplicates.

It seems redundant that we develop and maintain 2 separate Mobile Apps.

I have seen only posts that say a use case with 1 Mobile App and 2 BUs is not supported:

- [Switching Business Unit iOS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/332724/switching-business-unit-ios)
- [Mobile Push Sharing the same app in multiple business units](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/388375/mobile-push-sharing-the-same-app-in-multiple-business-units)
- [Connecting a Mobile App to multiple BUs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/367089/connecting-a-mobile-app-to-multiple-bus)
- [Initialize Mobile Push SDK twice in Mobile App](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/249487/initialize-mobile-push-sdk-twice-in-mobile-app)

But I can't see why not to do the following:

1. Crate a New App in each BU
2. When even a user is installing the app and logging in, we identify the relevant BU/Org he is part of
3. Register the user to his respective App on his respective BU/Org

Is this use case supported?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this approach is correct and will work, but as you expect, only one business unit will be able to send content to a given customer.

You would need to:

- Include two sets of integration parameters,
- Remember to set the `setDelayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet` ([iOS](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/sdk-implementation/user-data.html), [Android](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/sdk-implementation/device-contact-registration.html)) to `true` (it's `false` by default which could inflate your contact numbers)
- Get the contact key and correct business unit assignment
- Register the contact in the app with the correct set of integration parameters for the relevant BU

Answer (score 0):

Based on Rafał Wolsztyniak reply and SF support formal reply, It looks like the settings I suggested should work well.

Here is SF support's formal reply to my case:

Based on the structure you provided, where each Child BU is connected to a separate SFCRM Org, and there are no duplicate contacts, it is indeed redundant to develop and maintain two separate Mobile Apps for this use case. Instead, you can follow the best practice of using a single Mobile App that integrates with both Business Units' journeys and automation.

1. Develop a unified Mobile App:
   Create a single Mobile App that incorporates the functionalities and features required for both Child BU A and Child BU B. This ensures a streamlined user experience and reduces the need for duplicate development efforts.
2. Implement Business Unit identification:
   Include a mechanism within the Mobile App to identify the relevant Business Unit for each user. This can be achieved by using user authentication or capturing information during the registration process.
3. Utilize Marketing Cloud's SDK/API:
   Integrate the Mobile App with Marketing Cloud's SDK or API to enable seamless communication between the Mobile App and the Marketing Cloud platform.
4. Configure journeys and automation:
   Leverage Marketing Cloud's journey builder and automation features to create personalized and targeted journeys for users from both Business Units. Use decision splits and filters based on the Business Unit identification to ensure the right users enter the appropriate journeys.
5. Centralize messaging and content:
   Maintain a centralized repository of messaging and content assets within Marketing Cloud. This allows you to reuse content across both Business Units while customizing it based on user segmentation and Business Unit-specific requirements.
6. Leverage shared data extensions:
   Utilize shared data extensions within Marketing Cloud to store and manage user data across both Business Units. This ensures consistent data access and eliminates the need for duplicate data storage.